# convert the whole array of integers into object

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLCj7.png)

```
for i in predictions:     
    if i==0.0:
        i=str('Grade 1')        
    elif i==1.0:
        i=str('Grade 2')
    elif i==2.0:
        i=str('Grade 3')
    elif i==3.0:
        i=str('Grade 4')
    elif i==4.0:
        i=str('Grade 5')
```

there is no change in the array its not mapping please help

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you mean by 'categorical data'? And submission for what? Please also provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map in labels, `df` is your dataframe, and cols are `0` and `1`:

```
labels = pd.Series({
    0: "Orange",
    2: "Blue",
    4: "Red",
})

df[1] = df[1].astype(np.int)
df.join(labels.to_frame("label"), on=1)
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data (as text) and your code. We can't help you if we can't see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Using `rename_categories`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[random.randint(0,4) for i in range(10)]})
   A
0  3
1  4
2  1
3  1
4  2
5  3
6  1
7  1
8  1
9  0


#Must convert to categorical first then use rename_categories
 df.A.astype('category')\
    .cat.rename_categories(['Apple','Orange','Banana','Peach','Cherry'])

0     Peach
1    Cherry
2    Orange
3    Orange
4    Banana
5     Peach
6    Orange
7    Orange
8    Orange
9     Apple
```